# Pagination a way to control valid pages

Tags: php

I am using a script for Pagination to control the pages for amount of records shown on each page for a message system.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
                //PAGINATION//
        global $pagination;
        $total = $this->countInbox();

        $adjacents = 3;
        $targetpage = "messages.php?inbox"; //your file name
        $limit = 10; //how many items to show per page
        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }else{
            $page = 0;
        }

        if($page){ 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; //first item to display on this page
        }else{
            $start = 0;
        }
        /* Setup page vars for display. */
            if ($page == 0) $page = 1; //if no page var is given, default to 1.
            $prev = $page - 1; //previous page is current page - 1
            $next = $page + 1; //next page is current page + 1
            $lastpage = ceil($total/$limit); //lastpage.
            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; //last page minus 1

        /* CREATE THE PAGINATION */
        $counter = "";
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        { 
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
            if ($page > (int)$counter+1) {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$prev\"><</a></li>"; 
            }

            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) 
            { 
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a href='#' class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>"; 
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
            {
                //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) 
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a href='#' class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li ><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>"; 
                    }

                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>"; 
                }
                //in middle; hide some front and some back
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a></li>";

                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a href='#' class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>"; 
                    }

                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>"; 
                }
                //close to end; only hide early pages
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=1\">1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=2\">2</a></li>";

                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; 
                    $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a href='#' class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>"; 
                    }
                }
            }

            //next button
            if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage&page=$next\">></a></li>";
            else
                $pagination.= "";
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n"; 
        }
```

It works very well apart from one thing. If I manually input a page into the URL that doesn't exist it displays the page with no records such as

[image]

How can I stop manual input so that if a page=2, or page=3 does NOT exist then it will automatically redirect the user to a default page such as messages.php?inbox.

I am already using another function to control other valid pages.

```
$validPages = array('inbox', 'archive','compose', 'mid', 'trash', 'deleted');
$pageFound = false;

foreach ($validPages as $validPage) {
if (isset($_GET[$validPage])) {
    $pageFound = true;
    break;
}
}

if (! $pageFound) {
header("Location: messages.php?inbox");
exit;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to incorporate a fix in the function above.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I stop manual input

You can't.

You have no control over what your visitors ask for.

> so that if a page=2, or page=3 does NOT exist then it will automatically redirect the user to a default page such as messages.php?inbox

You know how many pages there are (`$lastpage`) and what page has been asked for (`$page`).

Just compare the two numbers.

```
if ($page > $lastpage) { ... }
```

You can then output a `404 Not Found` (or redirect, but a 404 would make more sense).